# Asynchronous test with Mocha and Chai GET doesn't work for Node.js Rest API

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

Thanks in advance for reading!

I'm struggling with testing even after looking for examples and tutorials, my tests are not working but I'm not sure if the issue is Chai related or my API server.

All the code is open source and available [here](https://github.com/fitigai/api/tree/refactor/crud-program-and-co).

I have an endpoint who should return all exercises as a list: GET `/v1/exercises`

Here is my test:

```js
'use strict'

const chai = require('chai')
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
chai.should()

const app = require('../src/app')

chai.use(chaiHttp)
const expect = require('chai').expect

describe('Exercise', () => {
  it('Should get all exercises', (done) => {
    chai
      .request(app)
      .get('/v1/exercises')
      .end((err, res) => {
        const result = res.statusCode
        expect(result).to.equal(200)
        done()
      })
  })
})
```

And I get this error:

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/Users/kevintassi/Documents/project/fitigai/api/test/01.exercise.spec.js)

You can see files here:

- [Test file](https://github.com/fitigai/api/blob/refactor/crud-program-and-co/test/01.exercise.spec.js)
- [Route file](https://github.com/fitigai/api/blob/refactor/crud-program-and-co/src/routes/exercise.js)
- [Controller file](https://github.com/fitigai/api/blob/refactor/crud-program-and-co/src/controllers/exercise/index.js#L11-L23)

Do you know why this issue occurs?
Note that I don't have this error is the endpoint is wrong, so the timeout is appear only when the function is processing I guess.
But still don't get why.

I thank you a lot in advance for your time. Feel free to ask me more details if needed.

Comment: Your API might take more than 2 seconds to respond that's why it fails. Increase the timeout to `10 seconds` using this parameter `--timeout 10000` and see if it works or not.

Comment: Hi Shaharyer, thanks for your answer.
Actually it doesn't work either. Added 20s so test but same issue. Even the api is responding faslty beside tests.

> Error: Timeout of 20000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/Users/kevintassi/Documents/project/fitigai/api/test/01.exercise.spec.js)

Comment: There is a possibility that `chai.request(app)` is not starting your server and the request is unsuccessful. Since you are not handling the `err` so you wouldn't know what is happening. Start the server separately and provide the exact URL to `chai`.

Comment: You could try adding a simple `console.log(result)` statement right before your `expect` to be sure that the response is really returned in time. Which I believe might not.

Answer (score 0):

Issue wasn't related to Chai or Mocha.

It was the way how my app and server were config. Just moving the DB connection to app instead of server solve the issue since mocha make the listen to the app automatically, it know include the DB connection.

This was causing the timeout issue.

Thank @Shaharyar for the help (in comment)

Comment: Can you please explain? How do you move the DB connection from the server to the app? App and server are 2 different things?

Please do let me know. Thank you.